# Spawn object in specific location

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey team,

I see a related question about spawning objects into the world via the command line.  Is it possible to spawn them into a specific location via the command line, or is the starting position and orientation set exclusively by the SDF file?  For example, if I have a moving platform and want to spawn objects on top of that, is there a good way to do that?

-Justin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4233/spawn-object-in-specific-location/) by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-08-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Use the `gzfactory -h` command line tool. You can specify an xyzRPY pose for a model.

You can also use [ROS way](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch#UsingroslaunchtoSpawnURDFRobots).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1